# Windows 8.1 Grouping For Products

Tags: c#, installation, inno-setup, windows-8.1

I want to add my products in one category as group on Windows 8.1 Start screen.
For Example.

Consider three groups GROUP1, GROUP2 and GROUP3.

Now i want to add my products PROD1, PROD2  AND PROD3 to GROUP1.
Similarly i want to add PROD4, PROD5,PROD6, PROD7  to GROUP2.

My question is how can i achieve this during installation of products and keep them in proper group.

Comment: Do you want to add it to the `Aps` section, or to the user's own Start Screen?  If you want to add it to the start screen, I would caution you against that.  I have my start screen set up **exactly** as I want it and I would dislike anyone's app trying to add their own stuff without me putting it there.

Comment: I am trying to add it to start screen.